# Joining the Column Outputs of Two or More Columns from a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am trying to join the outputs of two or more mysql queries. So if Query 1 has N columns and Query 2 has M columns, then the output should have N+M columns.
As an example:

```
select * from (select 1,2,3) as X,
              (select 4,5) as Y;
```

The output here is :

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Now the issue is that my second query may produce no results. This case results in no output at all:

```
 select * from (select * from table_0) as X,
              (select * from table_1) as Y;
```

If table_1 returns no matches, the combined output returns no rows.
I would still like to get the entries of my first table returned.

While I have a workaround, it involves individual queries for each of the M Columns.
I also do not want to create temporary tables and join them.

Comment: Yes! 1=1 is a great tip. And it worked fine in little example. I am going to package this into my application and see if my 221 seconds will be shaved down. Thanks to both Conrad Frix and Tim Burch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LEFT JOIN should do it:

```
select *
from (select * from table_0) as X
    left join (select * from table_1) as Y on 1;
```

Comment: Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4d74/3) demoing the answer. Feel free to include it your answer.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for catching that. Edited my answered accordingly.

Comment: Yes! 1=1 is a great tip. And it worked fine in little example. I am going to package this into my application and see if my 221 seconds will be shaved down. Thanks to both Conrad Frix and Tim Burch!